# Find nth number in a series of numbers containing either a power of 5 or the sum of unique powers of 5

Tags: algorithm

Find nth number in a series of numbers containing  either a power of 5 or the sum of unique powers of 5.
E.g.
The series can be like this 5,25,30(25+5),125,130(125+5),150(125+25),155(125+5+25)....

Comment: Please explain what how you've tried to solve this.

Comment: This looks extremely much like homework, and you didn't even bother to rephrase it to explain what you need help with and what you understand. I do call you lazy here. I hope your teacher/professor knows how to use Google (it indexes StackOverflow very thoroughly) to detect plagiarism/cheating. Also, per law and the contract you inherently agree on when posting a question or using an answer, you will need to correctly cite the answer, including nickname of the author and URL to her/his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a "sister" problem using 2 instead of 5. That would be

> Find nth number in a series of numbers containing either a power of **2** or the sum of unique powers of **2**.

The equivalent of your example would be `2, 4, 6(4+2), 8, 10(8+2), 12(8+4), 14(8+4+2) ...`. You can see from the example that in this case you would get the series of all even numbers. Thus nth number in this series is 2*n.

As you probably know by now, every positive integer can be written as a sum of distinct powers of 2. Because of this, the following holds. If we let `n=(b0,b1,...,bk)` be the bit representation of n, then the nth number in this 'sister' series is given by `Sn = 2*(b0*2^0 + b1*2^1 + ... + bk*2^k)`.

For instance, if `n=6=(0,1,1)` you get `S6 = 2*(0*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^2) = 12`.

To transform this in a solution for your problem, if `n=(b0,b1,...,bk)` is the bit representation of n, the number you are looking for is `Sn = 5*(b0*5^0 + b1*5^1 + ... + bk*5^k)`.